# Laggy TextField Updates in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, controlled-component

I'm relatively new to react and am having a little trouble understanding passing props/states from a child to parent component. I've managed to implement something that works but it is extremely laggy.

Overview: I am trying to create a form with multiple Material UI TextFields, with a submission button at the end to submit the form.

My approach: I am using state to update individual textfields on their inputs, and then dynamically updating another state in the parent FormSection file. Once the user clicks on the 'Submit' Button (not implemented yet), it will then take all the states from the parent class.

Existing Classes:

1. CompanyField.js
2. JobTitle.js
3. FormSection.js (Main File)

[Implementation Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL9ch.png)

CompanyField Class (will be same for Job Title, etc):

```
const Root = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
}));

class CompanyField extends React.Component {

  state = { company: '' }

  handleOnChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ company: event.target.value.toLowerCase() });

    this.props.onCompanyChange(this.state.company);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <Box
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
        >
            <TextField
              id = "outlined-basic" 
              label = "Company" 
              variant = "outlined"
              fullWidth

              value = {this.state.company}
              onChange = { this.handleOnChange }
            />
        </Box>
      </Root>
    );
  }
}

export default CompanyField;
```

Index Class

```
class FormSection extends React.Component {

  state = { company: '', jobTitle: '' }

  onCompanyUpdate = (value) => {
    this.setState({company: value})
    // console.log('Company:', this.state.company);

  }

  render() {
    return (
          <FormContainer>
            <FormContentHeaderWrapper>
              <FormContentHeader>
                  Company & Job Information
              </FormContentHeader>
            </FormContentHeaderWrapper>

             <FormWrapperFull>
               <CompanyField onCompanyChange={ this.onCompanyUpdate } />
               <JobTitleField onJobTitleChange={ this.onJobTitleUpdate } />
             </FormWrapperFull>
           </FormContainer>
    )
}
```

Could someone explain whether I am doing this the correct way? Else, would there be a better way to resolve this state passing method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `CompanyField` probably shouldn't have local state for `company`; you can control that from `FormSection`. Beyond that, there's nothing here that inherently seems "very laggy"; have you looked at your browser's performance tools to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: There's no need to call preventDefault() on an onChange event. As for your issue: keep the form state in the parent, then pass down the current value and a setter function as props.

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-currying-qvqcir?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for both your inputs! Helped me to understand state is not required in the child component and resolve the issue. Really thankful for Chris G's mockup as It really helped me visualise the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify for your example given, when onChange in the child is triggered, the state in the parent is changed, and then the value in the child will be updated with the state in the parent?

Answer (score 0):

When you update the parent component the whole tree re-renders on every keystroke. In your case your component very small it should not be a big impact. There are three approaches in my mind.

first of all, you have to use react developer tools for investigating further re-renders and finding the real problem.

first: You might use form validation libraries. For example; "react hook forms"

second: You might use React's "React.memo" function to memorize components.

third: You might use refs for input value management. You add values to ref and when you need them you iterate that ref object. You don't update the state. If there is no state update there will be no rerender.

for example:
In parent component:

```
const values = useRef({description: "", jobtitle: ""});

const onChange(name, value) {
  values.current[name] = value;
}
```

In child component: (it must be an "uncontrolled component")

```
const handleCompanyChange = (evt) => {
  const value = evt.target.value;
  const name = "company";
  props.onChange(name, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've looked at react hooks forms but I have not learnt hooks yet (am following a course on udemy), so I wouldn't want to use it for now. Will look into React.memo, and I will try out your 3rd solution - sounds interesting!

Comment: It was mentioned that uncontrolled components are not good for React in the course I'm taking, is that ok?

Comment: Mixing controlled and uncontrolled component isn't welcome. But you can use only one of them; it is ok. The downside of using uncontrolled components is that you can not update input variables programmatically.